# Proving if function is decreasing or increasing, then function is one to one

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, order-theory

My question reads: Prove that if the real-valued function $f$ is increasing (or decreasing), then f is one-to-one.

Here is my proof:

Let $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ be increasing (or decreasing) on $\Bbb{R}$

Let $x_1,x_2 \in \Bbb{R}$ s.t. $x_1<x_2$

**Case 1**

$f$ is increasing then $f(x_1)< f(x_2)$

$x_1< x_2$, so $x_1$ doesn't equal $x_2$, also $f(x_1)< f(x_2)$,  then $f(x_1)$ doesn't equal

$f(x_2)$ since $x_1$ doesn't equal $x_2$. Thus $f$ is one to one.

**Case 2**

$f$ is decreasing then $f(x_1) >f(x_2)$

$x_1< x_2$, so $x_1$ doesn't equal $x_2$, also $f(x_1) >f(x_2)$, then $f(x_1)$ doesn't equal $f(x_2)$ since $x_1$ doesn't equal $x_2$. Thus f is one to one.

Comment: I think you're a little bit confused. You're supposed to prove that $\forall x_1, x_2\in \mathbb R\left(f(x_1)=f(x_2)\implies x_1=x_2\right)$. If you did this, I can't understand how you did it. **Edit:** OK, I think I understand your answer now. I think you understand the problem correctly, but the proof is poorly written.

Comment: I did this same thing except I used the definition for all x_1,x_2 in R (f(x_1) doesn't equal f(x_2) then x_1 doesn't equal x_2)

Comment: @GitGud I think he (almost) proved that $x_1\ne x_2\Rightarrow f(x_1)\ne f(x_2)$.

Comment: Yeah I proved this instead. ( as a side note: I am a she)

Comment: @rogerl I understand that now. I was confused from the moment I read that "f is increasing then f(x_1)< f(x_2)".

Comment: @Sam Note that, for some reason, even though you typed "Let x_1,x_2 be in R s.t. x_1<x_2", only "Let x_1,x_2 be in R s.t. x_1" is displayed. This led to some of my confusion.

Comment: @GitGud yes I just fixed this I did not realize this was not showing up. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You start by saying that you assume $x_1 < x_2$. What follows is basically correct under that assumption. You did not, however, prove the result in the case that $x_1 > x_2$.

You could introduce cases 3 and 4 that prove things in the case $x_1 > x_2$ with $f$ increasing, and $x_1 > x_2$ with $f$ decreasing. However, the way I would approach this would be to replace the statement "Let $x_1, x_2\in\mathbb{R}$ with $x_1 < x_2$" with the following:

"Assume $x_1\ne x_2$. Then either $x_1 < x_2$ or $x_1 > x_2$. If $x_1 < x_2$, reverse the roles of $x_1$ and $x_2$. So in either case we may assume that $x_1 < x_2$."

Then proceed exactly as you did.

Comment: Okay then I need to assume x_1 does not equal x_2? But then how can I proceed with increasing and decreasing case.

Comment: You could split it up into four cases if you wanted, depending on whether $x_1 < x_2$ or $x_1 > x_2$ and on whether $f$ is increasing or decreasing. But it's easier to say that if $x_1 > x_2$ then rename $x_2$ to be $x_1$ and $x_1$ to be $x_2$ (that is, reverse the roles of $x_1$ and $x_2$) and proceed with the case you've already written down.

Comment: Can I not just split it up into two cases of f is increasing or f is decreasing?

Comment: Sorry, I think my answer is more confusing than it needs to be. Let me rewrite it.

Comment: I see now. The thing is my definition for increasing and decreasing both start with for all x_1,x_2 in I (interval) if x_1<x_2 then f(x_1)< f(x_2) (for increasing) and for decreasing it just changes to f(x_1) > f(x_2)

Comment: If we assume x_1 not equal to x_2 then wouldn't there be only two cases

Comment: Yes.  F is either increasing or decreasing.

Comment: Then when we consider x-1<x-2 we get increasing and vice versa the other way we get decreasing and the proof is done?

Comment: Would we have to do decreasing and increasing in both cases?